# Visual studio file sorting order

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to make visual studio sort files the same way that windows does, we have a number of scripts that are numbered ie. 1.sql, 2.sql ...100.sql.

In windows it shows up 1.sql,2.sql,3.sql...100.sql but in visual studio it shows up 1.sql,100.sql,2.sql....

Not really a big problem just slightly annoying when trying to figure out the next number to add.